# Mimic post request in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, http, post, python-requests

I have an app I'm using on my phone, which sends posts requests and gets back some info. I'm trying to mimic that post request from a Python script, and to get back the same response.

I used a packet sniffer to see what the request is:

```
POST /b/ss/wdgwespmaflm/0/JAVA-4.10.0-AN/s23376784 HTTP/1.1
connection: close
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1; en-US; HTC One_M8 Build/LMY47O.H4)
Accept-Language: en-US
Content-Length: 530
Host: w88.espn.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip

ndh=1&ce=UTF-8&vid=5f2c4950ca6e9359&pev2=ADBINTERNAL%3ALifecycle&c.&a.&DaysSinceFirstUse=52&RunMode=Application&HourOfDay=12&Resolution=1080x1776&DaysSinceLastUse=0&CarrierName=Partner&AppID=ESPN%20Fantasy%205.1.1%20%28155%29&TimeSinceLaunch=3&OSVersion=Android%205.1&PrevSessionLength=17&Launches=73&DeviceName=HTC%20One_M8&DayOfWeek=7&LaunchEvent=LaunchEvent&internalaction=Lifecycle&.a&.c&t=00%2F00%2F0000%2000%3A00%3A00%200%20-120&mid=61999711066602377445137974387884905365&pe=lnk_o&pageName=ESPN%20Fantasy%205.1.1%20%28155%29
```

I'm using the module `requests`, I tried this

```
r = requests.post("http://w88.espn.com/b/ss/wdgwespmaflm/0/JAVA-4.10.0-AN/s23376784", headers={
    'connection': 'close',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1; en-US; HTC One_M8 Build/LMY47O.H4)',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US',
    'Content-Length': '530',
    'Host': 'w88.espn.com',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip'})
```

but the script just gets stuck on the request. Where do i send the content? 
Should I not send it all as `headers`? I tried as `data`, it didn't work either.

Any thoughts?

Comment: First, your URL is not complete "/b/ss/wdgwespmaflm/0/JAVA-4.10.0-AN/s23376784", lacks protocol and host.

Comment: Use `http://w88.espn.com/b/ss/wdgwespmaflm/0/JAVA-4.10.0-AN/s23376784` as `URL`

Comment: ah ok..i'll try that

Comment: Still not getting a response back,

Comment: Try to add `ndh=1&ce=UTF-8&vid=5f2c4950ca6e9359&pev2=ADBINTERNAL%3ALifecycle&c.&a.& ...` to your request as `params` argument or add to the end of `URL`

Comment: no.. won't work..

Comment: program may first sends other requests to login or get authorization keys which it has to use in this `POST`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand last line from your packet sniffer is parameters you should pass to server. Try to concatenate `schema` + `host` + `resource locator` + `parameters`:

```
url = http://www.w88.espn.com/b/ss/wdgwespmaflm/0/JAVA-4.10.0-AN/s23376784?ndh=1&ce=UTF-8&vid=5f2c4950ca6e9359&pev2=ADBINTERNAL%3ALifecycle&c.&a.&DaysSinceFirstUse=52&RunMode=Application&HourOfDay=12&Resolution=1080x1776&DaysSinceLastUse=0&CarrierName=Partner&AppID=ESPN%20Fantasy%205.1.1%20%28155%29&TimeSinceLaunch=3&OSVersion=Android%205.1&PrevSessionLength=17&Launches=73&DeviceName=HTC%20One_M8&DayOfWeek=7&LaunchEvent=LaunchEvent&internalaction=Lifecycle&.a&.c&t=00%2F00%2F0000%2000%3A00%3A00%200%20-120&mid=61999711066602377445137974387884905365&pe=lnk_o&pageName=ESPN%20Fantasy%205.1.1%20%28155%29
```

or add these parameters as `params` argument:

```
params = {'ndh': '1',
          'ce': 'UTF-8',
          'vid': '5f2c4950ca6e9359', ...}
```

and send your request as

```
r = requests.post(url, params=params, headers=headers)
```

Comment: tried in all ways.. won't work.. Thanks for the help anyways!

Comment: Does this site requires authorization to perform your request?

Comment: I don't think so, this is the 1st packet the sniffer records from this app.

Comment: I think it might some firewall on the pc, i'll check that